# How do you set a boolean for whether a record exists in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set a boolean `$bln` according to whether a record exists in a table.

This is what I've been trying:

```
$bln = (bool) DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->pluck('id');
```

For some reason `$bln` always seems to be set to `true`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just do `$bln =DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->count() > 0`?

Comment: Yeah it seems I was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `count()` method:

```
$bln = DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->count() > 0;
```

If you'll need the object later, load it and use `is_null()` to do the check:

```
$object = DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->first();
$bln = !is_null($object);
```

Comment: So is the (bool) not needed at all?

Comment: @Urbycoz exactly. You'll get `boolean` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `id` is a `integer` and not `boolean` type? Well I really hope it is! hehe.
What you do is fetching the `id` of a given `account` and casting it to `bool`.
If you cast a value to `bool`, it will be **true** as long as it does not evaluate to **false**, in a `integers` case, only `0` will be evaluated to **false** when you cast it to `bool`.

Check if the result count is larger than `0` and it should give the result you want.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's an integer. Don't actually know why I'm bothering to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Because pluck() return an array, you can check it with count
`$bln = (bool) count(DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->pluck('id'));`
Here is a [Laravel Documentation: pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck/%22Laravel%20Documentation%20pluck()%22)

Comment: This code will load all accounts' IDs into the memory which is a bad idea. Imagine if you have thousands or millions of the accounts. It'll kill the request.

Comment: If we talk about performance your answer is better @AlexeyMezenin! I only want to show properly usage of pluck().

Comment: Laravel 4 actually returned a single value . That was only changed in 5.1 (I think). This is tagged laravel 4

Comment: Actually  you are right @apokryfos, Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `exists()` and `doesntExist()` methods give a boolean straight out of the box, use them instead of `count()`.

```
$bln = DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->exists();
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates): Determining If Records Exist

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$bln = DB::table('accounts')->where('name', $name)->get()->first();
if(isset($bln) && $bln != null || $bln != ''){
    return $bln = 1;
}
else{
    return $bln = 0;
}
```

Comment: This code will load all accounts to the memory and only then will get the first one.